# Re-create the "message" tag (or create a "message-stack" tag)

Tags: feature-request, tags

#### Modules with a dedicated tag

Tags such as [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views), [rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules), [userpoints](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/userpoints), [features](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/features), [quiz](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quiz), [webform](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webform), [panels](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panels), [feeds](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeds), ... etc are all tags named according to the Drupal module they are about. One could say "*Indeed, these tags are about modules with a lot of reported installs, and there are a lot of questions using these tags*".

However, there are also tags, also named according to the Drupal module they are about, such as these (the number indicates how many questions have been tagged with them): [bean](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bean) (28), [rng](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rng) (21), [devel](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devel) (21), [heartbeat](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heartbeat) (16), [webform-civicrm](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webform-civicrm) (14), [oembed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oembed) (13), [ical](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ical) (12), [jumpmenu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jumpmenu) (11), [homebox](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebox) (10), [markdown](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markdown) (9), [boxes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boxes) (8), [flowplayer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flowplayer) (7), [d2d](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d2d) (6), [aurora](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aurora) (5), [storm](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storm) (4), [bakery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bakery) (3), [skinr](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skinr) (2)

#### Attempt to introduce the Message tag

On Aug 4, 2017,  I created a similar [message](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message) tag (with excerpt and wiki), specific to the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. Here is how I documented the tag (the tag wiki):

> The [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is the core of the message stack and enables logging and displaying system events in a number of different use cases.
>   Related modules
>
> The other modules in the [message stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145) are:
>
> - [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify), to forward messages when they are generated.
> - [Message Subscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_subscribe), to register to be notified when messages are generated for specific content.
>
> These are the basic components and dependencies of the message stack:
>
> [image]
>
> #### Related tags: [notifications](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notifications) [logging](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging)
>
> #### Tutorials:
>
> - [Log Site Activity with Message and Rules.](https://www.webwash.net/log-site-activity-with-message-and-rules/)
> - [What is Drupal's Message Stack and how do its modules work together?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/105)
> - [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/109)
> - [How to allow users to manage their own Message Stack messages?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/82)
> - [How to use Rules to notify users about new or updated posts on a Drupal site?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/107)

Using an advanced search like '[is:q "message module" -private -popup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=is%3Aq%20%22message%20module%22%20-private%20-popup)' returns 45 hits these days. And I had applied this [message](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message) tag to these 10 questions (all specific to the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module) so far:

- [How to create a basic message - notifications system displaying a real time message counter badge?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/68867/39516)
- [How to use the Message module to log site and user activity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/68482/39516)
- [How to unflag all messages when a users visits the Message page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/69169/39516)
- [How to detect the newness of messages created with the Message module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/71380/39516)
- [Why would single-use (harcoded) tokens not validate in the Message module, when the dynamic version does?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/97984/39516)
- [How to mark a Message as 'viewed' when a user sees it in a View?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/120599/39516)
- [How to create a User Feed using the modules Message and Flag?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/194532/39516)
- [Which user related token(s) can be used to create a Rule for setting up a message type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/219680/39516)
- [How to show message view containing own and following activity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/222788/39516)
- [How to show picture of the user who triggered the rule for message activity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/234527/39516)

However, on Aug 5, 2017 a mass-rollback was performed for all those questions I had tagged with the [message](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message) tag. Due to which the tag got automatically deleted again (since it was not used anymore in any question).

#### Reasons for the Message (stack) tag to exist

The [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module already has a (RC) version for D8, has about 23K [reported installs](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/message) and is used in major distributions, such as [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons), [ERPAL](https://www.drupal.org/project/erpal) and [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium).

**`Over 20`** more questions specific to the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module:

1. [Message is created but text is empty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/98224/39516)
2. [combining messages and content types in views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/152750/39516)
3. [How get subscribe to user flag on a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/118894/39516)
4. [Why would single-use (harcoded) tokens not validate in the Message module, when the dynamic version does?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/97984/39516)
5. [How to add data to a message type custom field that's inherited by all message instances?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/127028/39516)
6. [Sending message notification based on flagged node being linked via entity reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/200845/39516)
7. [Conditional message text](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/105680/39516)
8. [How to put a custom message in the message module template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/237079/39516)
9. [How to show only Author Related Messages with Message module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/235830/39516)
10. [How do I use the message module with the flag?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/239927/39516)
11. [How to add missing data selector in "Create new entity" rules action?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/220767/39516)
12. [Why does the count of the Menu badge not decrease after page is viewed?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/210730/39516)
13. [How to make Drupal Commerce tokens available in the Commerce Message module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/243315/39516)
14. [Flag module integration with Message module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/181554/39516)
15. [How to use this Message Module with Services Module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/176166/39516)
16. [How to build and embed the output of a Message entity (from the Message module)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/86404/39516)
17. [How do I set the text format used in a message (from the Message module)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/69544/39516)
18. [Change the rendered output of a Message entity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/124747/39516)
19. [Should I use the Activity or Message module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/59278/39516)
20. [Tracking users 'advanced' activity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/233561/39516)
21. [How to create a view of all recent activity on a site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/57547/39516)
22. ... (on and on goes the list)

More of the same (questions related to other modules that belong to the [message stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145)) ...

- **`11`** more [Questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22message+notify%22) specific to the [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify) module.
- **`3`** more [Questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22message+subscribe%22) specific to the [Message Subscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_subscribe) module.

For all those reasons, please re-create the [message](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message) tag, or perform an undo of all rollbacks for the questions mentioned above. And if the [message](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message) tag would seem too confusing, then something like the [message-stack](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-stack) tag could be a valid alternative.

Comment: Why was the message tag rolled back/deleted? Why was my comment removed? Clearly a mod must of have been in here.

Comment: @NoSssweat I bet you know that "delete" does not really exist on SE sites, it is implemented as a synonym for "hidden from users with insufficient privileges". Depending on what is "*hidden*", it either requires to have sufficient rep, or to be a mod (such as for so-called-deleted comments). The only "delete" that I'm aware of that is really implemented as "delete" (aka gone, or distroyed), is the excerpt and wiki of a tag ... Therefor it will be interesting to see what the (new) initial content of the [tag:message] tag will look like, if it ever gets recreated. The bets are open ...

Comment: I once posted some questions about the Message module and also noticed that the tags were removed. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Jeroen I think I "know" the reason, but it might not be appropriate to write that down around here. What I did notice in the past though, is that quite a few of the tags that I ever created, and which got deleted again, later on were re-created by some other user (Group, Forena, etc). And since, then, those tag "live happy ever after". So maybe some day somebody else (like "Jeroen" for "Message"?) will succeed in getting the "Message" tag survive, or if you want the "Message-Stack" tag (would be OK for me too). For any suggested edit to add such tag, I approve upfront ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I don't think it is appropriate to imply that the mods are deliberately destroying what is specifically created by you. (It is not the first time I see you bashing on the mods or site policies.) If you do not feel welcome here, don't be here...  If it makes you feel any better, I've had tag suggestions denied as well.

Comment: @Neograph734 He did not imply anything. He is simply making a request and stated the facts. If anyone is implying anything, it's you. `If you do not feel welcome here, don't be here...` Are you implying that he should leave?